# Onedrive api to upload file

Tags: java, file-upload, onedrive, okhttp

I went through many references(including onedrive api doc) but i'm unable to upload a file into onedrive using okhttp request.

The following is the code that I tried:

```
    try {

            boolean status;

            String url = String.format("onedrive.live.com/v1.0/drive/root:/"+step.file_name+":/content"); 
//exceptions are not coming if i mention https:// in the url. but no output is coming

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(step.getContent_type()),step.getFile_data()))
                    .addHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s",step.getAccess_token()))
                    .build();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();


                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                status = response.code()==200 ? true : false;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return StepStatus.FAILURE;
            }
```

When trying from postman (PUT mapping) with the url "onedrive.live.com/v1.0/drive/root:/abc.txt:/content", it is redirecting to drive but saying the file may be deleted.

But, when I'm trying to generate url with file name and hit the drive, it's Showing success but the file is not saved/uploaded in drive.

How to upload a file to onedrive from the okhttp request?

Comment: Thanks, It's working for this Url ( https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root:/fileName:/content ) missed this `graph.microsoft.com`. i found that here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729433/corrupt-file-when-uploading-to-onedrive-using-graph-api-restsharp-and-dotnet-co][1]

Comment: I need to do something similar, can you give me pointers to this solution. the above stackoverflow link does not work.

Comment: @K.venkatesh Did it work for you? Could you please share your findings? I need to save the file to onedrive from my java application.

Comment: The link is broken, but the  graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root:/fileName:/content works for me. Thanks!